# Calling .NET 4.0 web service from ASP.NET 4.0 application generates a 403.1 error due to execute permissions

Tags: jquery, service

I have created a web service in .Net 4.0 framework as well as an ASP.NET 4.0 site.  They are both hosted on the same server but different sites.  I can access both sites with no issues and even invoke the web service methods with no problem by itself.  When I try to call the web service from an ASP.NET page using JQuery's ajax function it generates an error 403.1 execute permissions are denied.  I am confused as to what would cause this.  I running in IIS 6 on Server 2003.  Debugging the calls with Fiddler2.  Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was due to cross domain access, the primary domain name was the same however, the sub domain name was different. JQuery's ajax function does not like cross domain calls.